# Change active to inactive using buttons realtime

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter, datatable

I am using DataTables with ajax using PHP CodeIgniter Framework. I am having a problem with switching Active buttons to Inactive buttons, vice versa.

**What I want is:**

> When I click Active button, It should change to Inactive in realtime without refreshing the page.

**Controller:**

```
function activateStatus() {
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $data = array(
        'status' => 1
    );
    $this->equip_model->updateAccount('equip', $data, array('id' =>$id));             
}

function deactivateStatus() {
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $data = array(
        'status' => 0
    );
    $this->equip_model->updateAccount('equip', $data, array('id' =>$id));             
}
```

**View:**

```
<table class="table table table-hover table-bordered" id="equipmain">
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php 
       foreach ($equip as $row){
    ?>
        <tr>
          <td style="display: none;"><?= $row->id ?></td>
          <td align="center">
               <?php 
               $status = $row->status;
               if($status  == "1") { ?>                                    
                        <button id="<?php echo $row->id ?>" class="btn btn-xs green-jungle statusupdate1">&#10003</button>
               <?php } else  { ?>                                    
                        <button id="<?php echo $row->id ?>" class="btn btn-xs red-flamingo statusupdate0" >&#10005</button>
               <?php } ?>           
          </td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**AJAX:**

```
var oTable =  $('#equipmain').DataTable( {
            "searching": false,        
            "processing":true,
            "columnWidth": 20,                 
            "serverSide": true,
            "autoWidth": true,

        }); 

$(document).on('click', '.statusupdate0', function() {
            var id = $(this).attr("id");

            $.ajax({
                url: "<?= base_url() ?>Admin/activateStatus/" + id,
                success: function (data) {
                    oTable.ajax.reload();
                }
            });

        });

        $(document).on('click', '.statusupdate1', function() {
            var id = $(this).attr("id");

            $.ajax({
                url: "<?= base_url() ?>Admin/deactivateStatus/" + id,
                success: function (data) {                     
                    oTable.ajax.reload();
                }
            });

        });
```

I don't know where is the error why the buttons are not working.

Comment: what happens on the UI, are the buttons visible? what does not work visually.

Comment: @Andrei The buttons are visible. It does not do something when i clicked it.

Comment: check the console and can you please update what was the error, Is that the error is in jquery or else in controller code?

Answer (score 0):

It may be that you are missing the semicolon (`;`) after your `base_url()` call. In the AJAX section for both buttons, try changing `<?= base_url() ?>` to `<?= base_url(); ?>` and see if that solves the issue.

Comment: Can you provide the URL to the live site?

Comment: @JustinT. it won't create issue until you add one more variable or something next to that .